# Is having too many comparisons a valid reason to increase FDR threshold level?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

To briefly summarize, I have a bootstrapped data set that needs to be corrected for multiple comparisons. The figure below provides a snapshot of one set of the data. The x-axis is in bins of 60ms. That makes 51 data points (including 0.0s) for each of the experimental conditions. [image]

I am using the Benjamini–Hochberg FDR method and the BH critical value is defaulted to 0.05. The problem I have here is, given that I have 51 x 3 time points (red vs green, blue vs green, red vs blue), I have a whooping 153 p-values. The critical values at the top of the chart are currently so stringent that even a p-value of 0.02 did not make the mark of being significant.

In this scenario, is it a good reason to justify an increase in FDR value? If yes, what is a reasonable value to use? If not, what would be an alternative solution that I can use without needing to sacrifice too much lost in power?

Comment: Why are you testing all time points separately? To base the level of significance on the *outcome* of a multiple testing correction is a bad idea. You could however, exclude meaningless tests (*not* based on their $p$-values though).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I am looking at performance at certain time points vs other time points. I am aware that it is a bad practice to alter the FDR value. The reason why I am considering this for this particular study, is that there is a significant performance boost (uncorrected) that is seen consistently across 5 (out of 6) different studies, at the exact time points as well. In the 6th study that was insignificant, the p-value was straddling near 0.05. So it feels like the result happening by chance seems unlikely.

Comment: With pairwise comparison done however, more than half of the studies failed to beat the threshold. Thus, the idea of increasing the FDR value was brought up. Having said that, I think I'll take up the suggestion on removing time points that are not of primary interest to the study.